# python twisted elasticsearch connections

Tags: python, elasticsearch, twisted

i am developing an application in `twisted` python. aslo for the database i am using `elastic search`. now since twisted is asynchronous i cannot use the official python-es client. other async clients for elasicsearch are not updated for latest es versions. the option i have left with me is by using curl like options available i.e by maually hitting urls. but i think there is a downside to this approach , for every connection i need to make a authentication request to elastic search and also i can get too many open connections which i think is not good sine its hard to get connection pooling ( btw how to implement custom connction pool?) . what are the options for someone in my situation?

Comment: Just some question, why python-es client can not be used @~@

Comment: @PhongPhung becuase twisted is async framework and python-es client is blocking in nature(ie. setting up sockets,...) .i could not find any refrnce where it says its non-blocking. so it can not be used with any async fraework.

Comment: It depends on many factors, can you keep a connection opened or do you need to generate one for each request on your database? How are you using Elasticsearch (is it a single instance, is it a cluster, is there a coordinator mode...etc) ? By the way, what prevents you to use a different instance of an Elasticsearch client (thus using `elasticsearch-py`) per thread/process?

Answer (score 0):

There's [`txes2`](https://txes2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you could try that. Most of the libs out there for elastic search use the REST API so you could simply use [`treq`](https://treq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to make a wrapper yourself. But why reinvent the wheel :D